# VSCode. Auto suggestion to select from custom directive selectors in html does not work

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-code, angular-directive, autosuggest

I've installed some extensions to improve VSCode usages in angular project. Ones provide me choice to select from suggested menu correct value (in type script, in css and in html files). But I do not have this choice to choose selectors for my custom directives (neither as attribute not as property binding).

Is there any special extension for my issue or should I customize my VSCode (how)?

### More details

Beside custom directives I've detected that some angular's directives do not auto suggested also. For example, I try in `html` file in `<div>` directive **formGroup** or in any `input` **ngModel**, but no auto suggestions for this cases.

Comment: This is a MOST WANTED feature !

Comment: Now is 2022, Did you found any solution? @noririco